# AHK clipboard without trimming space and tabs

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey

I need to a change 3 small sets of html code lines in multiple webpages so I want try to use AHK to help me, with paste the code with a single keystroke, however, I don't get the code pasted well. When I use 'clipboard' it trims the tabs and when I don't use clipboard it doubles the tabs

```
F1::
Clipboard =
        <tr class="pure-table-odd">
        <td><label>Postcode<br><p class="kleiner"></p></td>
```

however, when I past this, all the tabs and spaces are trimmed

when I use

```
F1::
    <tr class="pure-table-odd">
    <td><label>Postcode<br><p class="kleiner"></p></td>
```

Anyone an idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [continuation section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation) with `` join`r`n `` and use [AutoTrim](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/AutoTrim.htm) but it won't be enough and you still need to escape the first tab with a backtick. Full code will be:

```
AutoTrim, Off

Clipboard = `
(join`r`n
        <tr class="pure-table-odd">
        <td><label>Postcode<br><p class="kleiner"></p></td>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems no way to solve this. But I found a good working alternative in which you create a multiple clipboard. You store the clipboards in variables in AutoHotKey. And paste them when needed. I found this script
Where you copy the clipboard with CTRL+1 ..... CTRL+2 etc.  and paste it with ALT+1  ALT+2 etc.

```
^1::
Send ^c
ClipWait
Clip1 := ClipBoard
return
!1::
ClipBoard := Clip1
Send ^v
return

^2::
Send ^c
ClipWait
Clip2 := ClipBoard
return
!2::
ClipBoard := Clip2
Send ^v
return
```

the original post can be found here [enter link description here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/24677-multiple-copy-and-paste-tool/)